# How to disable And enable spring boot KeyCloak configuration by parms passed through application.yaml?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, gitlab-ci, keycloak

I want to make my spring boot project keyclock  programmatically disabled and enabled by params passed throught app.lication.yml ,

```
server:
  port: 8095
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
  profiles: 
    active: ${project_secure:Notsecure}
```

by default, it will take "Notsecure", the variable $project_secure will be injected through gitlab.cy.yml

```
 - ansible-playbook -i deploy/inventories/dev/inventory deploy/playbook.yml --extra-vars "application_version=$PROJECT_VERSION profile_secure=$PROFILE_SECURE" --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.pwd
```

it's working correctly in my local workspace , but when i deployed to development environement , i'am always redirected to /login [image]

Always spring security is enabled!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add keycloak.enabled=false in application.properties

Comment: This doesn't work when we're using keycloak with spring security, right ?